# Java Scanner: NoSuchElement reading in plaintext file with map made of numerical characters

Tags: java, terminal, ascii, java.util.scanner

I keep getting the exception NoSuchElement relative to my scanning of the .txt file. Such errors to cause the exception are:

```
"java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)"
```

All I'm doing is reading in 1's and 0's as a test for a basic map in a ASCII terminal game.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Adventure {
    private Scanner in_file;
    private char[][] level;
    public Adventure() {
        level = new char[5][5];
    }
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Adventure adv = new Adventure();
        adv.load_game();
        adv.main_game();
    }
    public void load_game() {
        try {
            in_file = new Scanner(new File("level.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: Level could not be loaded!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < level.length; i++ ) {
            for (int j = 0; j < level[i].length; j++) {
                if (in_file.hasNextInt()) {
                    if (in_file.nextInt() == 0) 
                        level[i][j] = '-';
                    else if (in_file.nextInt() == 1)
                        level[i][j] = '#';
                }
            }
        }
        in_file.close();
    }
    public void new_game() { 

    }
    public void main_game() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                System.out.print(level[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    public void save_game() {

    }
}
```

My text file, "level.txt":

```
    11111
    10001
    10001
    10001
    11111
```

Comment: As far as `Scanner` is concerned, that file contains only five integers: `11111`, `10001`, `10001`, `10001`, and `11111`. It does not contain any instances of the integers `0` or `1`.

Comment: You should delimit your integers with whitespace (Default `Scanner`delimiter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code below, you read 2 ints instead of one:

```
if (in_file.hasNextInt()) {
    if (in_file.nextInt() == 0) 
        level[i][j] = '-';
    else if (in_file.nextInt() == 1)
        level[i][j] = '#';
}
```

This should solve the `NoSuchElementException` issue:

```
if (in_file.hasNextInt()) {
    int nextInt = in_file.nextInt();
    if (nextInt == 0) 
        level[i][j] = '-';
    else if (nextInt == 1)
        level[i][j] = '#';
}
```

But you also need to split the int into the figures that compose it (you can do that with divisions by 10, 100, 1000 etc. and rounding or by putting the int in a String for example).

Comment: No more errors, but nothing will print out! (I edited the print nested for loop to fit my 5x5 array)

Comment: because none of your ints is 0 or 1. See my last paragaph and the comments below your question. Separating the numbers with spaces in your file should do the trick if you can do that.

Comment: It works, thanks for helping! I am still pretty rusty with IO in general, hopefully with effort I'll get better next year in AP comp. sci., this is just some coffee-break game to help teach my friend java. :)